# How to target an anchor in CSS which is different from the other siblings

Tags: html, css

I have 5 siblings in an unnumbered list. They have an `<a>` element each.
4 of them needs to behave at the same way, when hovered they need to change their background color. One element does not change at all the background. How to target that specific `<a>`? I have tried to use an id, but it does not override the previous general target. I have tried pseudo class :nth-child with a combinator, but did not work.

```css
.nav-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3);
  /* padding: 10px;  */
  /* margin: 10px; */
}

#slot-1 {
  background-color: #AD6500;
  /* padding: 1rem;   */
}

#slot-3 {
  background-color: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  /* margin:0; */
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #AD6500;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-1">
        <a class="nav-bar-different-font-color" href="https://www.amazon.it">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-2">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">News</a>
      </li>
      <li id="slot-3">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">February 27.2021 - New feature: CSS oeverflow: overlay</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-4">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">Compare Browsers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-5">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: So for slot-3 you don't want the background colour to change when hovered? You could just modify your hover to NOT select slot-3 `li:not(#slot-3) a:hover`

Comment: For me all 5 have identical hover behaviour. Is that not what you need? Please clarify the expected behaviour.

Comment: @Huangism Thank you for the input, that's exactly what I want to do. I have tried to insert 'li:not(#slot-3) a:hover' at the end of the CSS but did not work. Please help.

Comment: @Matteo I posted an answer since no one else did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced your `a:hover` line with `li:not( #slot-3 ) a:hover`. Also I removed the bg none rule for #slot-3

What the above says is, target the `li` element that is not `id=slot-3` and target its descendant `a:hover`. So that for slot-3, this rule simply do not apply

There are other ways of doing the same thing but I think this is the cleanest

```css
.nav-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3);
  /* padding: 10px;  */
  /* margin: 10px; */
}

#slot-1 {
  background-color: #AD6500;
  /* padding: 1rem;   */
}

#slot-3 {
  /* removed, not needed */
  /* background-color: none; */
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  /* padding: 1rem; */
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  /* margin:0; */
}

li:not( #slot-3 ) a:hover {
  background-color: #AD6500;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-1">
        <a class="nav-bar-different-font-color" href="https://www.amazon.it">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-2">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">News</a>
      </li>
      <li id="slot-3">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">February 27.2021 - New feature: CSS oeverflow: overlay</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-4">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">Compare Browsers</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-bar" id="slot-5">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.it">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```